# how can I redirect to https which require certain sertificate for access

Tags: php, authentication, ssl, redirect, header

There's a payment server. I can successfully send data via cURL and set appropriate key and certificate and payment server successfully answers. But now I need to make a redirect to that server so that client can enter credit card data. How can I make that redirect?

Is there a possibility to add key/certificate as a part of headers in function header("Location: https://...."); ?

Comment: Are you sure the payment system works that way? Have you read the documentation?

Comment: Yes. If I install certificate in browser and enter redirect address, I get response. So I have to include certificate somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could send the certificate along with the redirect, the browser still has to verify it. But you can't. It's impossible. You have to send a regular redirect. Because it's a https address, the browser will first request the certificate from the target host and verify it (including necessary user intervention). The outcome is the same.

There is no way to circumvent the popup dialog requesting the user to accept/trust or deny the certificate. HTTPS is designed to ensure "reasonable protection from eavesdroppers and man-in-the-middle attacks, provided that adequate cipher suites are used and that the server certificate is verified and trusted." (Quote from Wikipedia)

Comment: ok, then I need to install certificate on the browser before redirection? or install this certificate on server so that it is applied during redirect?

Comment: ok, other side replied that for this task they have address that don't require authentication, so urgency for this question lowers, but theoretically it's still interesting how can it be accomplished. maybe it can be solved differently - using some sort of cURL authentication and just after it's done, redirect to pointed adress?

Comment: @banesto: If you don't install the certificate beforehand and the browser is configured to not automatically accept it, the user will get the known dialog saying "do you trust and should I remember your decision?". Why do you want to avoid that?  On your 2nd comment: You can write a script that acts as a proxy between the user and your provider. But again, why? The connection between your proxy and the provider would be secured by SSL, but if you don't secure the connection to the client the same way, you lower security. If you do, the problem stays the same just with a different certificate.

Comment: @rik there's no such dialog happening right now. Payment server has my certificate and knows exactly that it corresponds to me as a merchant. If I make cURL call, I set my private key, keyphrase and certificate so that they correspond to each other (but wihtout CA authentication), and then send data to Payment server. And it works ok. If I send data without sertificate stuff I just get BAD sertificate error, not "do you trust this server" dialog and that is exactly what is happening when I simply redirect to the server with some data.

Comment: @banesto: Of course there is no such dialog displayed to your PHP script. How should that work at all? If you redirect the user to a https site, he gets the dialog if his browser is configured to do so.

Comment: @rik I'm just sayin' that server does nothing unless I send it appropriate certificate. I installed certificate on a browser and only then I get the dialog which is fine.

Comment: @rik i'm not permitted do that

Answer (score 0):

Unless the provider has a very weird setup, I don't think you can. There are two clients cpnnecting to the server - first your PHP code which is using the client certificate, then you expect a browser somewhere to be able to bind to the same session without the client certificate? The only way this would make any sense is if the payment provider sends back a surrogate authentication token - and if they did that they'd provide detailled documentation. Obviously that is not the case.

While you could proxy the data on your server, I'd strongly recommend you switch to a different payment provider which handles the entire payment process for you.

Comment: thanks for reply! switching is not an option as I make demo shop particularly for this payment server.